# What type of noun is Majesty?

Tags: nouns, parts-of-speech

Consider the sentence, “Your Majesty, I was once the comedian of this court!".

What type of noun is Majesty? Is it proper noun or common noun or abstract noun?

My friend said that it is abstract noun but I didn't understand why it is an abstract noun. It can be a proper noun as it is referring to a particular person i.e. the king.

Comment: Note that while the answers correctly answer the question as posed, "your majesty" is a _set phrase_ (specifically, a form of address) that is not normally interpreted as ordinary words.

Answer (score 11):

By itself taken out of context, it’s an abstract noun because it’s referencing an abstract concept and not some physical object or entity.

When used as a form of address, it is a proper noun in certain usages, or an honorific in others. If used by itself as a form of address, it’s a synecdoche (a term used to refer to an entity by referring to some specific part or aspect of that entity, in this case referencing the office held by the individual being addressed) as well as a proper noun. If used as part of naming someone however, it’s a titular honorific similar to how ‘Doctor’, ‘Reverend’, or ‘Pastor’ is used as part of someone’s name.

Comment: Good analysis. I always test these things by replacing the object in question with _banana_. Then if I say to you, "I pledge allegiance to your Banana", this implies you own a banana and that I am now pledged to it. So we see that _Majesty_ is some attribute of the Queen (for example) to which we attach allegiance, respect etc. So it's not the person we're pledging to, it's this abstract thing that belongs to them (perhaps temporarily).

Answer (score 9):

The word "majesty" is an abstract noun. It means "the quality of being majestic". It's abstract because it refers to qualities of a person or thing. It is not a physical thing. The word "Majesty", with a capital M, is a proper noun. Literally speaking, it's still an abstract noun, but it is used as a synecdoche to refer to a royal person, and in that sense functions as a concrete noun.